# Javascript Access Multidimensional Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have this Object. i want to get the value of "label" dynamically. How do i do this?

```
var obj = {
  "Admin": true,
     "User": {
        "Someguy": [
          {
            "label": "NG59",
            "Id": 2094602823
          },
          {
            "label": "NG60",
            "Id": 3473631702,
          }
       ]
    }
}
```

What i've tried:

`Object.keys(obj.User)[0]`  // returns "Someguy"

`Object.keys(obj.User)[0][0]` // trying to get "label", returns undefined
`Object.keys(obj.User)[0].label` // undefined

How do i access "label" or "Id" dynamically?

Comment: Which of the two do you want to access?

Comment: both, actually.

Comment: Just use `obj.User.Someguy[0].label`. Or if you don't know the property name `Someguy`, it's `name = Object.keys(obj.User)[0]; obj.User[name][0].label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the key for the object to access the inner objects.

```js
var obj = { Admin: true, User: { Someguy: [{ label: "NG59", Id: 2094602823 }, { label: "NG60", Id: 3473631702 }] } },
    key = Object.keys(obj.User)[0];

console.log(key);
console.log(obj.User[key][0].label);
```

Comment: thanks alot!

`obj.User[Object.keys(obj.User)[0]][0].label;`

works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  "Admin": true,
  "User": {
    "Someguy": [
      {
        "label": "NG59",
        "Id": 2094602823
      },
      {
        "label": "NG60",
        "Id": 3473631702,
      }
  ]
 }
};

var guy = "Someguy";
var label = Object.values(obj.User[guy][0])[0];
console.log(label);
```

Comment: well, this returns label, not the value saved in label.

Comment: Replace `Object.keys` with `Object.value` to get the value.

Comment: And sorry, i forgot to mention, that i can't access  `.Someguy`, because its generated variable.

Comment: I've just updated